# Bitrix Tasks report

Tags: bitrix

I would like to pull the report of tasks with start date, end date, status of the tasks created in Bitrix of all users.

I have administrative access of Bitrix in self hosted version.

How can I get this?

Comment: It's seems, no one have expertise

Answer (score 1):

It was not clear from your question whether your question is about Bitrix Site Manager CMS or Bitrix24 Collaboration Platform.
If you mean Bitrix Site Manager, you probably mean Tasks 2.0. There is no information available on It in English, but you can visit the page https://www.1c-bitrix.ru/products/intranet/features/tasks.php#tab-report-link that describes on how to make reports on tasks, and translate it automatically, for example via the Google Chrome Browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the settings that come by default in bitrix, it generates a report but does not show all the information you want, some working time fields would be missing.

what you need is to create a new page in bitrix and using the bitrix api create a task report.

http://bxapi.ru/

thanks you.